# Resources for high level introduction into iCalendar rfc 5545

Tags: calendar, schedule, recurrence, rfc5545

I am grateful to have crossed paths with the 5545 spec.  However, I found that available resources on https://icalendar.org/ & from google are either *moderately* dense *or* lacking.

I was hoping to find an `iCalendar tutorial`, `iCalendar 101`, `Brief intro to iCalendar`, `RFC 5545 Crash Course` or similarly suited resource.

**What introductory resources are out there explaining how to use/implement rfc 5545?**  Also, is there a suitable competing spec?

I know that some people find these questions obnoxious, so I will confirm that "yes", I did search for a wide set of combinations of the term "introduction, icalendar, rfc, 5545, tutorial" etc before asking this community :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the [CalConnect Developer's Guide](http://devguide.calconnect.org/Table-of-Contents) helpful.